# Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.model.Named

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and this is my first project, and I got this error

`Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.model.Named PluginClassLoader[PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android, version=2020.3.1 Patch 3)] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@1cb18945'.`

and on top near the tabs this is the message I got

`Grade project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, all I did was download an earlier version of Android Studio and it worked flawlessly.